# How to build a pretrained CNN-LSTM network with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to use a CNN-LSTM network with Keras in order to analyze videos. I read about it and run into `TimeDistributed` function and some examples.

Actually, I tried the network described below, which is in fact composed by a convolutional and pooling layers followed by recurrent and dense layers.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(2, (2,2), activation= 'relu' ), input_shape=(None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer = 'adam' , metrics = ['acc'])
```

I haven't tested properly the model, since my dataset is too small. However, during training process the network reaches **accuracy 0.98** in 4-5 epochs (perhaps it is overfitting, but it isn't a problem yet because I hope to get a suitable dataset later).

Then, I read about how to use a pretrained convolutional network (MobileNet, ResNet or Inception) as a feature extractor for LSTM network, such that I use the following code:

```
inputs = Input(shape = (frames, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
cnn_base = InceptionV3(include_top = False, weights='imagenet', input_shape = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))

cnn_out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(cnn_base.output)
cnn = Model(inputs=cnn_base.input, outputs=cnn_out)
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(inputs)
encoded_sequence = LSTM(256)(encoded_frames)

hidden_layer = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(encoded_sequence)
outputs = Dense(50, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer)
model = Model([inputs], outputs)
```

In this case, when training the model it always shows **accuracy ~0.02** (it is the baseline 1/50).

Since the first model at least learned anything, I am wondering if there is any error with the way the network is build in the second case.

Has anybody faced this situation? Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: Since your dataset is smaller, you should try freezing some layers of the InceptionV3. The remaining layers will then learn the features and yield better accuracy.

Comment: I try using this code in Tensorflow 2.9 and I resulted in the following error:


NotImplementedError: Exception encountered when calling layer "time_distributed_42" (type TimeDistributed).

Please run in eager mode or implement the `compute_output_shape` method on your layer (TFOpLambda).
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you have very small amount of data and retraining the complete Inception V3 weights. Either you have to train the model with more amount of data OR train the model with more number of epochs with hyper parameter tuning. You can find more about hyper parameter training [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/).

The ideal way is to freeze the base model by `base_model.trainable = False` and just train the new layers that you have added on top of the Inception V3 layers.

OR

Unfreeze the top layers of the base model(Inception V3 layers) and set the bottom layers to be un-trainable. You can do it as below -

```
# Let's take a look to see how many layers are in the base model
print("Number of layers in the base model: ", len(base_model.layers))

# Fine-tune from this layer onwards
fine_tune_at = 100

# Freeze all the layers before the `fine_tune_at` layer
for layer in base_model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:
  layer.trainable =  False
```